# log4j2: multiple appenders the same output is written to multiple files

Tags: spring, spring-batch, log4j2

I am working on a spring batch project that has two batches with a separate launcher for each one.
I'm using log4j2 for logging with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30" status="info" xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
<properties>
    <property name="patternlayout">%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} [%method:%line] - %msg%n</property>
    <property name="filename_first_batch">c:/logs/batchs/first_batch.log</property>
    <property name="filename_first_batch-pattern">c:/logs/batchs/second_batch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip</property>
    <property name="filename_second_batch">c:/logs/batchs/first_batch.log</property>
    <property name="filename_second_batch-patten">c:/logs/batchs/second_batch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip</property>
</properties>

<Appenders>
    <!-- the standard-console-appender -->
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" />
    </Console>

    <!-- appender for the first batch -->
    <RollingFile name="appender_first_batch" fileName="${filename_first_batch}" filePattern="${filename_first_batch-pattern}"
        append="false" bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- appender for the second batch -->
    <RollingFile name="appender_seond_batch" fileName="${filename_second_batch}" filePattern="${filename_second_batch-patten}"
        append="false" bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Root>

    <!-- first batch logger -->
    <Logger name="com.mycompany.batch.launcher.FirstBatchLauncher" additivity="false" level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_first_batch" level="ALL" />
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Logger>

    <!-- second batch logger -->
    <Logger name="com.mycompany.batch.SecondBatchLauncher" additivity="false" level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_second_batch" level="ALL" />
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_first_batch" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_second_batch" level="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_first_batch" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="appender_second_batch" level="info" />
    </logger>

</Loggers>
```

When I run batch launcher, I get the log files created correctly,
however if any of the batch launchers is started, it writes the same output to the other file.
What I want is that every batch logs its output to the dedicated file.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are launching the batch jobs with a scripts. If you include -DjobName=batchJobName where batchJobName is the name of the file you want to use you can then use ${sys:batchJobName} to determine the name of the file.

Comment: file name is already specified in the log4j2 config, besides, I've tried your advice and it didn't work, I still get the same output log written to the other files